# Slow downing emulator speed

Tags: c, emulation, simulation

I'm trying to implement emulator main loop. Emulator runs at full speed. About 60 Mhz. But I want to make it run at 4.77Mhz. How it's done ?

```
for (;;)
{
        emu_step(ctx) ;
        uint64_t current = get_gtod_clock_time () ;
        uint64_t elapsed = current - last_time ;
        if (elapsed >= 1000000)
        {
            printf("Cycles: %d\n", get_cycles(ctx)) ;
            set_cycles_zero(ctx, 0) ;
            last_time = get_gtod_clock_time () ;
        }
}
```

`emu_step()` is function which executes one instruction. `get_cycles(ctx)` is sum of executed machine cycles. `set_cycles_zero(ctx, 0)` sets cycles counter to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because `emu_step` is being executed at every iteration of the for loop, if you moved it inside the `if`, then it would only be executed when `elapsed >= 1000000`. In that particular case you could execute it once, independently from the loop, so that you don't have to wait one throttled `cycle`.

It could look something like

```
emu_step(ctx) ;

for (;;)
{
        uint64_t current = get_gtod_clock_time () ;
        uint64_t elapsed = current - last_time ;
        if (elapsed >= 1000000)
        {
            emu_step(ctx);
            printf("Cycles: %d\n", get_cycles(ctx)) ;
            set_cycles_zero(ctx, 0) ;
            last_time = get_gtod_clock_time () ;
        }
}
```